# GWT Textbox with only Spaces

Tags: javascript, html, gwt

I am using GWT textbox and I am setting its value to few spaces - textBox.setValue("          ");

But they don't seem to appear inside the textbox. Even if I set the value like this - textBox.setValue("          A"), it only displays 'A' inside the textbox. Not sure what the issue is. I even tried using setText() API instead of setValue() API but no luck. Even If I manually edit the generated HTML and add the attribute value="          A", it does not appear on the Textbox.

Am i missing something?

Comment: Is it because it is a proportional-width font, and spaces only take up a small amount of width, so it is not obvious that they are there?

Answer (score 0):

Try using textBox.setText("                    A");